# How to make a service update the UI on an activity after reopening after the system has shut it down in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a simple timer app. The timer runs in a service and broadcasts messages to the activity class so as to update the ui with the timer-clock counting down. Works fine when you are just keeping the app open with it on the screen and also when it goes for like about less than 25 minutes in the background. But after 25 minutes in the background it seems the system shuts down the activity because when I go back to the app the screen no longer is updating the ui like it was earlier. I have the broadcast receiver being made in both the oncreate and onResume areas of the ui class. What can I do so that the class gets updated even after what I imagine is the OS killing it after 25 minutes?

Comment: ever considered using a widget perhaps for these tasks? a service will update your widget periodically. if you need to update an activity consider using a storage which will be updated and when your activity is up will just re-read the storage with freshest data. and if service sees the activity it will update activity directly. perhaps so.

Answer (score 0):

The os kills your service, cause it thinks it's dead. If the user hasn't used it in 25 minutes, the os is likely right. What you need is a [STICKY_SERVICE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).  Also, I agree with @Sergey Benner. I would use a widget. Much more user friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not going the widget route. I'm going to try this and I'll update with my results.

Comment: you'll need some method of storing the remaining time if (when) the service is killed. I suggest storing the start time in a preference.

Comment: OK. So STICKY_SERVICE just says restart the service if called. Looks like there is no easy way to keep a service running. I guess I need to capture the remaining time when ondestroy of my service is called. Then compare it to the restart time. Calculate the difference. Make a new time. Send that back to the service. Repeat for every time the system arbitrarily closes my service. I'm not a big fan of this OS big bullying programs. But what if my service isn't restarted? The timer never goes off which is the whole point of the app. Bizarre. Don't know where to go actually.

Comment: Now, that I think about it, why do you even need a service if the user has to open the app just to look at the timer? If they must open the app, then you can just save the start time as a preference or in a file somewhere and recalc the time everytime you open the app. Then just update the widget with a repeating handler call.

Comment: They don't have to open it. Being that it's a timer that people would rely on for important stuff it has to work if they open it or not. Some people might want to see the clock ticking down and open it. Others might want to just leave it till it goes off. Anyhow, I put in the startForeground(ID, notification) method and so far so good at least on the first long test.

Comment: Right, but If the timer only works (ie, the user only sees that the timer in the activity) then you don't need a service. You just save the start time to a file or something, and then every time the user opens the application, the file is loaded, the real time is calculated and displayed. If you want an alert to fire at a certain point, then just register an alarm event and await it's broadcast. which will then post a dialog or something that the countdown has completed. There isn't a need for a service from what you are telling me.